# System.FormatException occurred in mscorlib.dll when converting it int32

Tags: c#, wpf

I know, i know there are lots and lots of questions asking on here about this error, each with their own response, but its easier to work off a response regarding your own code rather than someone else's

I have been working on this program for some time for a college assignment, and as soon as i started putting in the class to calculate the totals of things it now crashes,

I don't know where to look so i'll post my main code

```
enter code here
namespace Till


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
     Calculator calc = new Calculator();


    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


    }

  public  bool User;
    public bool tillopen = false;


    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //button clone thingy

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        label.Content = label.Content + btn.Content.ToString();
        Console.Beep(); // makes the buttons beep 

    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear

        label.Content = "";

    }

    private void Button_Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // submit
        listView.Items.Add(label.Content);
        label.Content = "";
        calc.setSoldItems(Convert.ToInt32(label.Content)); /// it breaks on this line///
    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //void sale
        label.Content = "";
        listView.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //pound
        label.Content = "1.00";
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //till open close

        tillopen = true;
    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Login m = new Login();
                    m.Show();
        this.Close();

    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label.Content = "2.00"; // 2 pound
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label.Content = calc.finish();
    }
}
```

I have tried to re-create the error in another WPF (converting a to an int32) and it works fine, i know this is an issue with my code itself, i have tried using other machine and using different versions of visual studio itself, so we came to the assumption its this code itself and not a broken dll file

So before I sit down with my Teacher and spend all day going though my code step by step im asking around for help in order to save both of our time, This assignment is due in in 3 weeks, and it decides to break on me now.

thankies

To replicate this error, i press a number button on my Windows form, them hit the submit button i created (which starts the conversion) If a copy of my class which handles all of this is needed im happy to post it

Answer (score 0):

In the method **button_click**, you have assigned value as

```
label.Content = label.Content + btn.Content.ToString();
```

which is a string value to the label and the values are concatenated instead of add.

and when you are reading it, you are converting it in Int32. which will give exception as it will not contain any integer value to it.

You can add the value like this:

```
  label.Content = (Convert.ToInt32(label.Content) +  Convert.ToInt32(btn.Content)).ToString();
```

and check before converting if the label has blank values in it, if it has do not convert them, and only convert the value if it has some values it will not give any error. Also do not assign any values other that numerical digits.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating:

```
Convert.ToInt32(label.Content)
```

but on the line before you set:

```
label.Content = "";
```

so this means you are calculating

```
Convert.ToInt32("")
```

which gives you a `FormatException`.

Perhaps you should use the value of `label.Content` ***before you overwrite it***?